# Controls not responding in UIPopoverController on initial load but do on subsequent loads?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an app that is loading a overlay controller (shows camera so I can scan).  It works great on the iPhone and it works great on the iPad after I call it a second time.  Let me explain.

I have a UIButtonBarItem that loads a view controller modally.  There are several controls on in the controller, most buttons (defined using a nib).  If I load the controller (by responding to the UIButtonBarItem action) on an iPhone, it loads and all the buttons work fine, every time.

But... if I load the same view controller using an UIPopoverController, none of the buttons will respond the first time I load it.  So, I touch the screen somewhere outside of the controller and dismiss the controller.  Then, I touch the same action button again and now when the controller loads, all the controls in the the view controller work great. REALLY WEIRD!

[POSSIBLE HINT]
The buttons were placed all over the place in weird positions when I loaded it the first time.  Each subsequent call had the buttons showing in the right places.  I got this to work by disabling "Autoresize subviews" in the nib.  The buttons are now in the right places but they still won't respond when I load this popover the first time.

Here's the code I'm using to respond to the UIButtonBarItem.

```
 -(void)launchOverlayController:(id)sender
 {
if([pickerControllerPopover isPopoverVisible])
{
    [pickerControllerPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    pickerControllerPopover = nil;
    return;
}

// Deselect any selected cell
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow animated:NO];


// Working code that shows the overlay (camera on) but the overlay takes the whole screen
SRSScanVINViewController *scanVINViewController = [[SRSScanVINViewController alloc] init];
[pickerController setOverlay:scanVINViewController];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:scanVINViewController];
[navController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[navController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    pickerControllerPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pickerController];
    [pickerControllerPopover setDelegate:self];
    [pickerControllerPopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0f, 460.0f)];
    [pickerControllerPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
else
{
    [self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

 }
```

I'm totally out of ideas.  I can't see why the controls within the overlaycontroller would work fine every time I call it except for the first time.

Thanks for anyones help in advance.

Comment: I've tried the code using a regular modal view controller and NOT the PopoverController.  If I use the regular controller, it works every time INCLUDING the first time.  It seems to have something to do with the PopoverController.

Comment: I've also noticed that the first time I launch the Popover controller, it comes up almost immediately (and of course it doesn't work).  Each subsequent time I launch it, it works fine but it takes about 2 seconds longer to load.  Obviously, something additional is happening when I load it the second time (and each time thereafter).  I've stepped through the debugger and don't see any methods called differently.  Is there something that gets done (or not done) the first time a popover controller loads?

Comment: Create a small demo project that demonstrates the problem. Upload it to your DropBox account in the public folder, and update the question. Fixing real code will be much more productive for everyone.

Comment: Hah - that was a one time invite and someone else grabbed it. Can you put it in your public folder and update the link? Offer 50 points and the sharks start circling the boat!

Comment: I've done a small sample app that shows the behavior. It integrates with the RedLaser SDK. If you run the code in the simulator, it'll simply say you don't have a camera and provide a fake barcode scan. Either way, you'll see the described behavior. To get to the popover controller, click on the "plus" sign in the master controller. Here's the URL to the dropbox location for the code:https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dcomloipqr4poxp/xuOMczCGDf

Comment: Since I solved your problem, and you awarded me the answer, it would be great if you gave me the bounty. I believe all you do is click on the +50 next to the answer (but never did it myself). You can read up more on bounties here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: I burned a lunch at work to fix your problem. You offered a bounty for the solution, but never awarded it to me, and in one day it just expires and disappears. Would you please spend the 1 minute of time and tap on the award button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer is that the superclass is mucking with your view. I'm going to guess it was not designed to be subclassed, but no way to know for sure. What it does in one of the 'view..' methods is to override self.view with its own view, and make your view a subview of that view. The first time around it makes the frame of your view have zero dimensions. The next time it leaves it as it was before - maybe some persistent flag. It also inserts the view at different places in its subviews, which seems odd but if you have the code you'd probably see why.

Soooo - the solution to the problem is to just move your view's subviews to the superView (the subclass's view), then set your view's frame to the null frame:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];  // StackOverflow says to add this TCL?

    // Set the initial scan orientation
    [self setLayoutOrientation:self.parentPicker.orientation];

    if ([self.parentPicker hasFlash])
    {
        [flashButton setEnabled:YES];
        [flashButton setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered];
        [self.parentPicker turnFlash:NO];
    } else
    {
        [flashButton setEnabled:NO];
    }

    textCue.text = @"";
    viewHasAppeared = NO;

    // move the subviews    
    while([self.view.subviews count]) [self.view.superview addSubview:[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0]];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,0,0);
}
```

PS: note that you were missing a superView call here but it didn't seem to matter much (you don't know which method your complex superclass may want so I'd be sure to send them everything you intercept.

Comment: That was it! Brilliant!  How did you figure that out.  I'd like to know so that I can find things like this in the future.  I'm just starting out with IOS and have a lot to learn.

Comment: I wrote some routines that walk the views - I think I posted them on SO will look later. I kept looking for some view in the window or a subview of the view that would block touches, nothing. So on a guess I looked at 'self.view.superview' and I saw the view owned by that library - when I dumped its views out I saw that what you thought the view you were using had gotten stuffed in that view - it happened late in the game.